Any Cheap LiDAR Capable of 3D Ranging a Road?
I am working with an academic team attempting to use LiDAR to range road surfaces to detect potholes and other hazards. We've been looking for a "Cheap" LiDAR that could give us a decent area point cloud. We only need ranging for down the road in front of the vehicle so the FOV doesn't need to be that large but the range should be quite high (To see a decent way down the road). I've seen some posts asking similar questions but they all seem to be 5+ years old. Is there any technology that fits what we are looking for that is <$500? Thanks for any help.
